# Проблема с OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

Пытался подписать сертификат по инструкции на этом сайте https://losst.ru/sozdanie-sertifikata-openssl, в итоге он выдает мне ошибку при обращении к demoCA, подскажите пожалуйста что с этим делать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот конфиг файл, я его не менял от слова совсем [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сообщения об ошибках и конфиги следует вставлять текстом

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: В ошибке написано, что нет такого файла по данному адресу. Путь к файлу и название совпадает с путем и файлом , который правили?